# Rake task to update records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing a rake task that is scrapping a website in order to find concerts:

**lib/tasks/my_task.rake**

```
  task :find_concerts  => :environment do

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    data = doc.search('#dateconcert table')
    data = data.css('.jaunec' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) } + doc.css('.jaunef' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) }

    data.each do |concert|
      c = Concert.new
      c.date = concert[0]
      c.city = concert[1]
      c.save
    end
  end
```

**What I want**

I want to get an alert when a new concert is added ( on the website I am scrapping), so the tasks will be run everyday.

**My problem**

I want my Concerts list to be updated if there is a new record...

With the task I wrote it finds again the records that are already stored and duplicated them... 
I only want the new records that could be found...

In the end I would like to compare what is new between the two last tasks in order to send an alert if something new was found.

**EDIT**

This is what `data` returns

```
[
 ["03 Décembre 2017", "PONT L\u0092ABBE (29)  | Centre Culturel Le Triskell "],
 ["26 Janvier 2018", "MONTPELLIER (34)  | Le Jam "],
 ["17 Février 2018", "BLOIS (41)  | All That Jazz / Les Lobis "], 
 ["22 Mars 2018", "MOISSAC (82)  | Hall de Paris "],
 ["24 Mars 2018", "LAX (Baraqueville) (12)  | Festival Lax'N Blues LAX\u0092N "],
 ["08 Décembre 2017", "ECHANGE CULTUREL CAMEROUN (0)  | au 18 décembre 2017 - Organisation tournée MFR "],
 ["27 Janvier 2018", "LE THOR (84)  | Le Sonograf "],
 ["16 Mars 2018", "CHAUMONT (52)  | Le Nouveau Relax "],
 ["23 Mars 2018", "AUCH (32)  | Le Cri'Art "]
]
```

Comment: Isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: I've just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that may need some refactoring, though.

So I created two tasks,

- `find_concerts` that will be run manually for the first scrap
- `update_concerts` that will be run every day

**task**

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
require "date"
require "time"

 namespace :scrap do

  desc "This get MM concerts"

  url = "http://mountain-men.fr/concerts/"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  data = doc.search('#dateconcert table')
  data = data.css('.jaunec' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) } + doc.css('.jaunef' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) }

  task :find_concerts  => :environment do
    data.each do |concert|
      c = Concert.create
      c.date = concert[0]
      c.city = concert[1]
      c.save
    end   
  end

  task :update_concerts  => :environment do
    existing_date = Concert.all.map { |c| [c.date, c.city] }
    data.each do |concert|
      c = Concert.create
      c.date = concert[0]
      c.city = concert[1]
      c.save unless existing_date.include?([concert[0], concert[1]])
    end
    Concert.where(city: nil, date: nil).destroy_all
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but what you need to do is to check if it exists and other wise create.

I would do some thing like this.

```
  task :find_concerts  => :environment do

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    data = doc.search('#dateconcert table')
    data = data.css('.jaunec' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) } + doc.css('.jaunef' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) }

    data.each do |concert|
      Concert.where(data: concert[0], city: concert[1]).first_or_create
    end
  end
```

Now you only create if it doesn't exist. Then when you create one you can set a hook.

```
class Concern
  after_create :send_notification

  def send_notification
    # send email here
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the same result as with mine